# How to use a sequential combination of YAML parameters in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How can I use a sequence of parameters, assigned using YAML in Rmarkdown? I am trying to write a csv file, but I can only use one param.

For instance. I have:

```
title: "My Title"
params:
  month: "March"
  person: "CEO"
  extention: ".csv"
```

I want to add all of the assigned parameters as a single continuous word:

```
write.table(d, file=params$month params$person params$extention, quote = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", sep = ";", row.names=FALSE)
```

However, its not possible like that, it only reads one parameter if put like that.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file attribute has to be a string so you can use `paste` to put it all together as one string. (`paste0` is the same as paste but doesn't put a separation between the variables by default)

```
write.table(d, file = paste0(params$month,params$person,params$extention),
             quote = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
```

will give "MarchCEO.csv"

In your case you only had month for the name of the file, the other variables were not taken into account because of the space, so it thought it was some other attribute..

if you want the line to be more readable you can define the name first like that:

```
myfilename <- paste0(params$month,params$person,params$extention)

write.table(d, file = myfilename, quote = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8",
            sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you. There is no reference about this anywhere I've seen

Comment: Glad I could help. Basically any variable from a function which has a string input (something with " ") can be built up with paste. Paste is used to concatenate things together (text, numbers, variables) and output it as a string. (as.character). If you use paste (rather than paste0) you can speciffy the link between the words to use with its own sep option)

Comment: Right on. I use paste a lot, but that separator was the issue. I was trying with quotation marks and other separators( | : '  space etc), all except the comma, because I assumed that would separate variables in the function